# Variable argument list to JavascriptCore block

Tags: iphone, ios7, objective-c-blocks, javascriptcore

I'd like to define a function in the JavascriptCore context that takes a variable amount of arguments.

Something like this:

```
JSVirtualMachine* virtualMachine = [[JSVirtualMachine alloc] init];
JSContext* ctx = [[JSContext alloc] initWithVirtualMachine:virtualMachine];

ctx[@"func"] = ^(JSValue* value, ...){
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, value);
    for (JSValue *arg = value; arg != nil; arg = va_arg(args, JSValue*)) {
        NSLog( @"%@", arg);
    }
    va_end(args);
};

[ctx evaluateScript:@"func('arg1', 'arg2');"];
```

I believe that the JSC wrapper doesn't pass the second argument to the block, because iterating on `va_list` crashes after logging the first argument.

I also tried with the `NSArray*` convention, it doesn't work.

Is this possible in any way?

Comment: I also tried to do this when defining a Objective-C console log handler that took multiple args, but could not get it going even using NSLogv.  A  messy approach - you could try serialising the args into a single arg via JSON then unpacking it in your Objective-C handler.

Comment: Yeah that would be a last resort approach. There's actually a way to do it using the regular C API, with `JSObjectMakeFunctionWithCallback`, but I'd like to go away from that C interface so ARC can handle JS Value's memory.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From JSContext.h:

```
// This method may be called from within an Objective-C block or method invoked
// as a callback from JavaScript to retrieve the callback's arguments, objects
// in the returned array are instances of JSValue. Outside of a callback from
// JavaScript this method will return nil.
+ (NSArray *)currentArguments;
```

Leading to the following:

```
ctx[@"func"] = ^{
    NSArray *args = [JSContext currentArguments];
    for (JSValue *arg in args) {
        NSLog( @"%@", arg);
    }
};

[ctx evaluateScript:@"func('arg1', 'arg2');"];
```

Comment: That's also a great way to get JSValue objects from arguments. Just figured out that getting JSValues as block arguments (like `ctx[@"func"] = ^(JSValue* value){...}`) leaks the passed values. It sounds like the block retains the value so, the context retains the block, the block retains the value, and the value retains the context.

Answer (score 1):

I like @erm410's answer, I had not seen the documentation on currentArguments.

Another approach I have taken is to pass a JSON object to an Objective-C NSDictonary. One benefit to this approach is that you have named arguments - though you are dealing with string literals that will need to be typed correctly between the call and the handler.

```
ctx[@"func"] = ^(NSDictionary *args) {
    NSLog(@"%@", args[@"arg1"];
};

[ctx evaluateScript:@"func({'arg1':'first','arg2':'second'})"];
```